# Spark not receiving streams from Kafka?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Iam trying to stream logs/topic from the kafka to the pyspark script.

I have used Docker Spark cluster to submit this job

I have done following configuration so far

```
# Used 2182 for both zookeeper and kafka, since 2181 was already used
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties 

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties


bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic event --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic event --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic event --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Here the producer and consumer is working fine.. where i am able to see the message exchanged

So in the script, i used the port 9092 as the same used by producer and consumer

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json
from pprint import pprint

sc = SparkContext("spark://<mymaster>:7077",appName="Kafka-logs")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,5)

print("Pyspark Launched")

kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'localhost:9092', 'event', {'imagetext':1})


#print('contexts =================== {} {}');
lines = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
lines.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()

##below is the spark-submit i used

docker run --add-host="localhost: <myec2ip>" --rm -it --link master:master --volumes-from pyspark_vol spark-submit_update spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.1.1  --jars /home/spark/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.6/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.1.1.jar  --master spark://mymaster:7077  /data/spark_kafka.py localhost 9092 –topic event
```

But i am getting below error:

```
TimeoutException: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000
```

so i chaged the port to 2182 in the script as it is

```
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'localhost:2182', 'event', {'imagetext':1})
```

after that, spark submit issue got resolved . But found that the script is continuously listening to the stream, even i passed topic from producer and not producing output from the script

```
Time: 2020-09-08 05:35:05
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-09-08 05:35:10
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-09-08 05:35:15
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-09-08 05:35:20
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-09-08 05:35:25
-------------------------------------------
```

i am not understanding this type of issue and how to resolve it?

Appreciated for the help?

Thanks

Comment: why are you using Spark Streaming instead of Structured Streaming?

Comment: Hi Alex, its part of the requirement and kind of POC , i using Spark Streaming..